# Hibernate tool to create basic mappings based on a mysql db

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, reverse-engineering

Are there any tools that can look at a database, and generate the basic mapping files?

It would be great if it could take a database, and create the actual model (java classes) with annotations, but not sure if that exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hibernate 3 has a toolset called [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) that provides an Eclipse plugin and an Ant task that both support **Reverse Engineering**:

> **Reverse Engineering:** The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is a database reverse engineering tool that can generate domain model classes and Hibernate mapping files, annotated EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation or even an entire JBoss Seam application in seconds!
>
> ...
>
> **Ant task:** The Hibernate3 tools include a unified Ant task that allows you to run schema generation, mapping generation, or Java code generation as part of your build.

For the Eclipse plugin, have a look at [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#d0e890) of the documentation. For the Ant task,  have a look at the section about [reverse engineering](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e2530) and optionally how to [control it](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html).

Note that other IDEs also provide support for reverse engineering (see [Hibernate Reverse Engineering for Netbeans 6.5](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ReverseEngineering) and [Generating Persistence Mappings from Database Schema](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jpa_hibernate.html#link5) for IntelliJ).

Answer (score 1):

I just happened to stumble across this problem and I think I have found a perfect tool for the job.

http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/

---

**Features :** (in case you are lazy to go through the provided link)

- Java objects representing each table using annotations for use with Hibernate.
- A JUnit test case per table that uses the objects generated to create, populate, save, retrieve and compare results
- DAO per class
- The appropriate enumeration files
- Spring and hibernate configuration
- DAO layers
- A data factory class per schema to return a pre-populated object with random data (for boundary checking, database population, etc)

**Also supports:**

- Join tables including those with additional fields in link tables
- Polymorphism/inheritance support
- Composite Keys
- One-To-One, many-to-one, many-to-many, etc
- Multiple schema support (4 modes)
- Natural Keys
- Enumerations (including those entries which cannot be mapped cleanly onto the java world)
- A whole bunch of more stuff (see sample.xml)

---

I would also like to say that setting this up is quite straight forward; You just have to have a hibernate configuration file and the jar file downloaded from the site. Then it's just a matter executing a jar file, passing the `config.xml` as a parameter!

Comment: Thanks a lot..This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse or ant...

[Jboss tools](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html)

Answer (score -2):

You might find what you need here, I found it on the fly: [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1505).

I know there are others that exist, but I don'T remember by heart. Hope this helps!